# How to pass around android context inside the clean-architecture

Tags: android, android-context, clean-architecture

regarding the Clean-Architecture: If i understood correct you would have a pattern like MVVM to interact with the user and completely separated from this you would have a module that handles framework request. Does this mean that the framework part would handle the request to share a text with the android system dialog? If thats the case, how would I get the context (required to start the dialog) to the framework module? If I pass it down through the layers, wouldn't that make my app less testable and probably more vulnerable to errors regarding the android lifecycle?

Comment: You may find this helpful, the difference between getContext(), getBaseContext(), and getApplicationContext() [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22)